# Global Entry and documents with name mismatch?

Tags: usa, global-entry, tsa-precheck

I am a US permanent resident interested in applying for Global Entry.
There is a typographical error in my Green Card (it mistakenly includes middle name which i don't really have). My application to correct the mistake is still pending with USCIS.

All my other documents such as state ID, foreign passport are all have my name printed correctly.

Will this fact cause a problem for my Global Entry application, and given it's approved, after when I will use TSA Pre/Global Entry?

Comment: What do you mean you "don't really have" a middle name? Does a middle name appear on your birth certificate?

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica Many cultures don't even have the concept of a middle name. Others use something else entirely, such as a patronymic, which Americans usually substitute as the middle name in official documents.

Comment: @MichaelHampton True. I'm curious where the mismatch began. If USCIS won't amend the green card (and they might decline, if other documents proffered by the OP show something to suggest a middle name exists), then a GE application is vulnerable to being declined, and the OP may face challenges even the GE application is granted. I expanded this a bit in my answer.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica Yes, as Michael Hampton said there is no middle name concept in the country i'm coming from. What USCIS did is that they used my patronymic as my middle name. The biographic page in my foreign passport is fully in English and has no mention of patronymic at all. The only place they could get it from is my birth certificate translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A name mismatch could delay your Global Entry application, or cause it to be denied. Even if your application is granted, and a Global Entry card issued to you, the name mismatch could conceivably generate difficulties for you in the future, especially at any US immigration point including preclearance locations overseas.

It will be far easier for you to travel if all your official government documents show the same name.

Prudence suggests that you delay applying for Global Entry until the documents you already possess present a consistent statement of your name. That is, apply to USCIS to issue a replacement Green Card showing the same name as appears on your foreign passport and state ID. After a new Green Card has been issued to you showing the consistent same name, then apply for Global Entry.